# Why the design of c++ does not allow passing the lhs object to an operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, operator-keyword

i am writing since i would like to understand something *about the design of C++.*

The question is the following: in C++ it is possible to overload a class operator by passing two rhs values. however there is no way to obtain information about the 
output to which these operations are applied.

think for example to the implementation of a Matrix class:

the relevant code would look something like

```
    template <typename DataType, int NumberOfRows, int NumberOfColumns>
    class Matrix
    {

        DataType _data[NumberOfRows * NumberOfColumns];

    public:
        typedef DataType TDataType;

        Matrix() {}


        ...missing code...


        template <int SecondNumberOfColumns>
        friend inline Matrix<DataType, NumberOfRows, SecondNumberOfColumns>
        operator*(Matrix const& First,
            Matrix<DataType, NumberOfColumns, SecondNumberOfColumns> const& Second) 
        {
            Matrix<DataType, NumberOfRows, SecondNumberOfColumns> result; //HERE THE ALLOCATION OF A TEMP IS NEEDED

            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < SecondNumberOfColumns; j++) {
                    DataType temp = DataType();
                    for (int k = 0; k < NumberOfColumns; k++)
                        temp += First(i, k) * Second(k, j);

                    result(i, j) = temp;
                }

            return result;
        }

    }
```

the * operator needs to allocate a temporary, implying that if one wants to do an operation like A = B*C either has to hope for compiler optimizations or go for techniques such as expression templates.

**I would like to understand what is THE DEEP REASON for which the design of C++ did not include the possibility of writing something like**

```
    operator*( 
        ReturnType& out, <---- THIS WOULD BE THE RETURN
        Type1& input1,
        Type2& input2
    )
    {...}
```

in which the "out" is passed explicitly when passing the operator (the point is that such a syntax should still map to the user writing 
 out = input1*input2)

I am asking my question since this would greatly ease writing a lot of libraries, and **i guess the solution was considered and discarded**. I would love a didactic explanation of why this option was not admitted

thank you in advance
Riccardo

Comment: Ummm, NRVO and move semantics are a thing now. In fact, NRVO always was. Did you *measure* your example as inefficient, or are you assuming?

Comment: just write prod(output, in1, in2) and compare it. It is a fact that move semantics help. It is also a fact that it does not solve everything.

Comment: Compare what? Your example doesn't exhibit a type whose default construction is cheap. Passing an "output" operator is going to be no better than NRVO (that every compiler worth its salt does).

Comment: just take a look at http://www.meeting-cpp.de/tl_files/2014/talks/Expression%20Templates%20Revisited.pdf . In any case operators are there since ever. move semantics is there only since 2011. The question of WHY it is not allowed is fair (at least to me)

Comment: In C++ an expression has a type and value regardless of context; `input1 * input2` can not be different if it happens to have `out =` before it

Comment: Also I doubt the claim that the suggested signature would "make it easier for libraries" or , as you seem to imply , be more efficient. On almost all implementations, even if you disable copy elision, this "allocation" is just moving the stack pointer

Comment: The fact that move operations are only introduced in C++11 is rather irrelevant. C++11 is common by now. The suggested syntax is not in C++11, not in C++14 and won't be in C++17. My bet is that it won't land in C++20 either, as it is inferior to move/RVO.

Comment: @MSalters: To be fair, there are places where "move/RVO" doesn't work. These are places where the type is a pure-value type (so copying is equivalent to moving), and where correctly doing the operator work *requires* creating a named object. That is, you can't do `return type(...);` to compute the value. So you're left at the mercy of NRVO. But even in that case, we'd rather have a way to *ensure* NRVO (essentially, giving us direct access to the return prvalue) than to do this combined `operator*` and `operator=` stuff.

Answer (score 9):

> I would like to understand what is THE DEEP REASON for which the design of C++ did not include the possibility of writing something like  in which the "out" is passed explicitly when passing the operator (the point is that such a syntax should still map to the user writing out = input1*input2)

That mapping is the problematic part. It presupposes that `out` is an object which *already exists*. So obviously code like `auto out = input1*input2;` would be impossible, since `out` *does not exist* as an object until the `operator*` finishes execution.

And what if the default constructor value initializes the object? There's no reason to pay that cost if you're just going to overwrite the object. Better to let `operator*` create the object for you than for you to create an "empty" one.

And that doesn't even consider types that don't allow default construction or otherwise "empty" states at all.

More importantly, it would make simple statements like `out = input1*input2*input3` impossible. This manifests at least one temporary object during its evaluation. In your model, where does that temporary object come from? In the regular C++ model, it's the return value.

Or in more rigorous C++17 speak, the prvalue returned from the first `operator*` will be used to manifest a temporary object, which is used as the argument for the second `operator*` call. This is no different from any other function which returns a prvalue.

At the end of the day, C++ is predominantly a value-oriented language. Expressions of multiple parameters resolve to a single value; that's the standard way things work. Sure, you can create the effect of an output value via a reference/pointer parameter. But that is generally not the way the language wants to work. It may sometimes be necessary, but you generally want to compute values.

And operators are among the part of C++ that is most value-oriented. `a + b * c` produces a single value. This ought to be able to initialize an object (`auto x = a + b * c;`) or work on an existing object (`x = a + b * c;`). It should not require that the return value already exist; that's an implementation detail, not an interface requirement.

Comment: *"C++ is predominantly a value-oriented language"* - Succinct and to the point.

Comment: Dear Nicolas, thank you for the kind explanation.
still indulge me to ask a bit further
The exact syntax is a detail. But one may might still define two versions of the same operator
1 - with two arguments (the traditional), for the case in which the output does not exist
2 - another one with 3 arguements (the one that is impossible) for the cases in which the output does exist. You could still template it and accept an expression if you want to have out=in2*mult_expr(in2,in3)

Comment: @RiccardoRossi: But why add all that complexity? What's the point? If it's something you really need, you can handle it as a direct function call. But operators do not operate on their return values; they *produce* a return value.

Comment: i see your point. Still achieving the syntax out=in1*in2 without temporaries requires using expression templates, which IMHO is pretty complex. It would be nice if there was a way to map explicitly that syntax to a given call, say prod(out,in1,in2) for example as this function may be implemented in BLAS. I think now this cannot be achieved.

Comment: (forgot to say thx)

Answer (score 0):

How would you call an operator that took 3 inputs like you suggested?  The only way I can think of calling it would be to use the verbose operator syntax:

```
m.operator*(out, in1, in2);
```

But if you're going to do that, you might as well just write an ordinary, named member function and be done with it.

Overloading operators is in large part designed to make natural syntax for math expressions with value-type objects that behave in ways consistent with numbers.  What you want is not natural syntax for using an operator, and would only complicate the language with little/no tangible benefit.

Comment: The OP already said, "*the point is that such a syntax should still map to the user writing out = input1*input2*". So that's how you would call it.

Comment: That is not a very satisfying syntax, considering operator= may already be overloaded, and it does not compose beyond a single invocation.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong; it's a *terrible idea*. And that's actually a very good point about `operator=`, though I imagine that it could be handled as a case of (decidedly oddball) overload resolution. That is, if the three-parameter operator could be called for the given types, it would be in favor of the `operator=`.